# How can I get a coupon for "first item free"

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

It's hard to believe that this hasn't been done before, but I can't find any information or documentation on how to accomplish this.

If there are multiple items in the cart that share an attribute, I want to have a coupon code that will make *only* one item in that collection free. (preferably lowest cost item, but i'll settle for just "first" in whatever order)

Ex. (custom attribute is `color`)

- Item 1 *color=red* $5.99
- Item 2 *color=blue* $6.99
- Item 3 *color=blue* $7.99
- Item 4 *color=green* $8.99
- Item 5 *color=blue* $9.99

SubTotal = $39.95

Coupon would be to the effect of "first blue item free", and after applying, it would look like the following

- Item 1 *color=red* $5.99
- Item 2 *color=blue* $0.00
- Item 3 *color=blue* $7.99
- Item 4 *color=green* $8.99
- Item 5 *color=blue* $9.99

Is anyone aware of an extension that covers this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, none of the extensions I have used do this, but some quick searching yielded this result: 
http://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-advanced-promotions.html

It looks like it will do what you want, but I would ask the developer first (as always) to make sure.

Comment: actually found that same extension. shortly after posting, but thanks for the suggestion!